# Filtering Deleted Objects

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, database-design, django

Picture a simple messaging app written in Django.
Users have the option to delete messages at any time, but the messages need to be retained in the database. There are two options:

- A `deleted` attribute on `Message`. Then the call `user.messages.all()` would be replaced with `user.messages.filter(deleted=False)` everywhere in the code. This seems like it could create hidden bugs and is unintuitive.
- Create a separate `DeletedMessage` object. This violates the principle of having similar data in one place, but allows for simpler method calls (i.e. `user.messages.all()`).

Which method is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've inadvertently highlighted a code smell.

`use.messages.filter(deleted=false)` should only appear *once* in your application.

You mentioned that all the calls to `user.messages.all()` would need to be changed, but that's not true.  Instead of having several calls to your "GetAll" function, you should wrap that in a reusable abstraction like a respository or a service.

If you don't do that, you're effectively duplicating logic and making maintenance difficult.

Comment: Good point, didn't realize it was a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new column in the message table, `Deleted` (bit).
2. Create an updateable view on the message table that excludes the deleted messages.
3. Build your data access for messages around the view.